# Why does a ZFS scrub offline a disk after some errors, but onlines the disk after a reboot?

Tags: hard-drive, zfs

Yesterday during a monthly scrub, `zpool` offlined a disk after 61 errors, and urged me to replace it. I ordered a new one. Until such time, the status was *"degraded performance."*

Today, when powering on the computer, the drives were doing a lot of work. When it stopped, I did a `zpool status`, and to my surprise everything is online again.

```
  pool: pool
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices has experienced an unrecoverable error.  An
    attempt was made to correct the error.  Applications are unaffected.
action: Determine if the device needs to be replaced, and clear the errors
    using 'zpool clear' or replace the device with 'zpool replace'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-9P
  scan: resilvered 924M in 0 days 00:00:40 with 0 errors on Fri Dec 14
config:

    NAME                 STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    dataset              ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0           ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-Seagate_xxx  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-Hitachi_xxx  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-Samsung_xxx  ONLINE       0     0    61
```

I expected to either:

1. Have the failed drive OFFLINE permanently; or
2. Have the failed drive ONLINE during scrub, resilver, and warn me.

I assumed ZFS would either try to keep using a disk for parity, or decide a disk is *too* broken, and not use it ever again (unless manually forced to try again). But apparently, **ZFS changes its mind after a reboot.**

Why do I care? **Because now I learned I should always try a reboot.** Not so I can ignore the warning, but so I keep having parity while waiting for another disk. It's better to have parity with a degrading drive than not have parity at all. If I wait a week for a disk and *another* disk fails, I will have a high chance of recovering the majority of the data, versus definitely losing all data when the previously failed drive stays offline.

**In summary;** the failing drive state went from `ONLINE` to `OFFLINE` during scrub, and from `OFFLINE` to (online but) `DEGRADED` after a reboot. I expected it to either stay `OFFLINE`, or go from `ONLINE` to `DEGRADED` during scrub.

Why does this happen? What am I misunderstanding?